# SonarQube: How to configure leak period start every X days

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I'm Using SonarQube 5.6.5 and trying to configure it so that the Leak Period is starting every x (=21) days.

Our sprints are running 21 days so I want the differential view is showing the changes since last sprint start.
I get this only if I manually change each sprint start the 'Leak Period' to the date of the sprint start. 
Is there a more convenient way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

[Fixing the Water Leak](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/Fixing+the+Water+Leak) (paradigm at the core of SonarQube features/UX) is about making sure that your software quality does not degrade from one product version to another, which is why the default value of the Leak Period is *since_previous_version*.

By definition of a *sprint*, your software should be releasable at the end of each sprint. If you do release an increment at each sprint then the default *since_previous_version* will do.

And actually even if you don't release every sprint, *since_previous_version* still is the best pick:

- quality since last released version is what you should focus on (if you didn't release after the previous sprint, then you shouldn't ignore bugs/vulnerabilities/code_smells potentially introduced back then)
- it will still ensure that quality does not degrade in the course of one sprint (*since_previous_version* being a sort of superset of 'since last sprint')